Show window of script running on VM of Azure Pipeline agent
I have an Azure DevOps pipeline which I want to start a long running test. I only want to start it and not wait for the results. (test will for example be a performance test running over the weekend).
What I want to achieve is that when I RDP onto the VM with the azure pipeline agent running, I will see the scripts that I have started.
What I have: run-stresstest.ps1 which starts another long running powershell script (my-tool.ps1)
My yml file:
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: 'Run stress tests'
    inputs:
      script: |
        cd /d c:\StressTest
        set VSTS_PROCESS_LOOKUP_ID=
        start powershell.exe c:\StressTest\run-stresstest.ps1

My launcher ps1 script: run-stresstest.ps1
    Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-File ./my-tool.ps1" | Out-Default

So what I am missing is to see the window in where the script my-tool.ps1 is running. I'd like to see the output and be able to interact (by stopping the script) with it if needed.
Now I don't see anything, but I see that that my-tool.ps1 is running in the process manager.
I used the logic of Child process of an Azure DevOps task is killed when the job stops to prevent my scripts/processes to be killed automatically by devops after completing the task.
Environment:

Selfhosted windows azure pipeline agent (running as user)


This is a strange use case for a build agent. What exactly do you mean by I'd like to see the output and be able to INTERACT with it if needed?

@RuiJarimba With interact I mean to stop the script. So I want my pipeline to set everything up (install programs that have been build, and start the test (script). This will run for x days, but I want to be able to logon onto the VM, look at the logging created and stop early when needed. (When I have enough data)

@RvdK Can you check the steps in the answer and check if it can meet your requirement? We need to use Interactive mode self-hosted agent and set the variable: Process.Clean to false.

I found a solution/workaround. Via Powershell I create a scheduled task and then execute it. This makes the Powershell windows shown on VM so I can watch it running.
The PowerShell script is created so that when passing a flag it will create a scheduled task which calls itself without the flag (which is normal operation).
My yml file:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Run stress tests'
    inputs:
      filePath: 'c:\StressTest\run-stresstest.ps1'
      arguments: '-ScheduleStressTest'

run-stresstest.ps1:
param(
  [switch] $ScheduleStressTest
)

$scheduledTaskName = 'MyOwnTask'

if ($ScheduleStressTest) {
    Write-Host "Scheduling stresstest"

    # Delete task if already existing
    if (Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $scheduledTaskName -ErrorAction Ignore) {
        Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $scheduledTaskName -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
    }

    # Create new task to start the stresstest (itself)
    $taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "-NoProfile -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""c:\StressTest\run-stresstest.ps1""" -WorkingDirectory "C:\StressTest"
    Register-ScheduledTask $scheduledTaskName -Action $taskAction -RunLevel Highest
    Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName $scheduledTaskName
    return
}

# Normal flow
# start my services and execute my test



I'd like to see the output and be able to interact with it if needed.

To meet your requirement, you need to follow the following points:
1.When you create the Self-hosted Agent, you need to use Interactive mode self-hosted agent. For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Install the agent
2.Azure Pipeline will clean the process after running the Pipeline tasks by default.
To avoid this behavior, we can set the variable: Process.Clean to false
For example:
variables:
   process.clean: false

steps:
- powershell: 'Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-File test.ps1" | Out-Default'

Result sample:
Pipeline:

Local Output:


Thank you for response. My agent was already running as Interactive but that didn't help with showing the spawned powershell windows with output. The process.clean is a helpful command this prevents the need for the cmdline task in the yml file.

@RvdK Can you try to use the PowerShell Task to replace the cmd task and run the same commands? You can check if you can see the PowerShell window output.
